# Can I walk through a multidimensional array in PHP and convert the type from strings to integers if they contain only numbers?

Tags: php, type-conversion

I have a multidimensional array that has some values that are strings, and some values that are numbers. When I convert the array into a JSON object, I get a result that looks like this:

```
"A" : "1", "B" : "Text", "C" : "3"
```

The goal is to have a JSON that looks like this

```
"A" : 1, "B" : "Text", "C" : 3
```

Before, I was accomplishing this by editing the JSON after it had been encoded:

```
$JSON = preg_replace('/"(-?\d+\.?\d*)"/', '$1', json_encode($array));
```

But that has been problematic for a whole bunch of reasons.

So, instead, before converting the array into a JSON with `json_encode()`, I'd like to step through all the values and make sure that if a value is a number, then they type for that value is changed from `string` to `int`.

I know I can set the type of a variable in PHP with the settype() command:

```
settype(int, $variable);
```

I think that I need to combine that with a command like `array_walk()`, but I don't know how I would combine it in a way so that it does a test to only act on numbers.

Is it possible in PHP to hunt through a multidimensional array, find values containing only numbers, and convert them into an `int` type?

Comment: Something like, [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option:

```
$array = array('A' => '1', 'B' => 'Text', 'C' => '3');
echo json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Or you can loop over the array:

```
$array = array('A' => '1', 'B' => 'Text', 'C' => '3');
foreach ($array as & $value) {
    if (is_string($value) && ctype_digit($value)) {
        $value = (int) $value;
    }
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Edit: Just for posterity, the `&` turns `$value` into a reference (which points to the actual content of the array item), as opposed to just a variable with a value.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option of [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) since PHP 5.3.3 that is supposed to do this : [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php).

Comment: I just wanted you to know that I gave the green check to the other answer because both options were provided,but that your answer is much appreciated for quickly solving my ultimate JSON issue. Thanks.